# How to convert TIFF to JPEG?

Tags: c#, freeimage

I am trying to convert a TIFF file to JPEG using FreeImage.

The problem is that `FreeIamge.SaveToStream` doesn't actually do anything. Even after the call, `stream` has a `Length`, `Capacity` and `Position` of 0.

This is my code:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var image = FreeImage.LoadEx(fileName);
    FreeImage.SaveToStream(image, stream, FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_JPEG,
                           FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.JPEG_QUALITYSUPERB);

    // stream.Length, stream.Capacity & stream.Position are all 0 here
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try rewinding the stream first, see if it persists.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why using the `MemoryStream` at all? Why not just call `SaveToStream` directly on the `FileStream`?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: That doesn't help. [`MemoryStream.WriteTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.writeto(v=vs.110).aspx) writes the *entire* contents of the `MemoryStream` to the other stream. This is documented. Furthermore, I checked: The `MemoryStream` has a length, capacity and position of 0.

Comment: @vcsjones: Because this is a boiled down example code from my real code in which I need this step in between.

Comment: So the question is why `FreeImage.SaveToStream` does not actually do that.

Comment: And whoever downvoted that question should leave a comment, so I can improve it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I guess so, yes

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Simplified the question, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the input - a 16 bit image created by another image library. It looks like FreeImage has some problems with 16 bit images as GDI+ could read it without problems. I switched the input to a 24 bit image and the code in my question started working.

Comment: Sigh... the joys of libraries that are not using exception handling. [Seems that `SaveToStream` returns a `bool` for success/failure](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/fnet/html/4A01CFCD.htm).

Comment: "GDI+ could read it without problems" -- GDI+ could read a 16-bit TIFF? My experience with PNG files (I just ran into this) is that System.Drawing.Image (.NET wrapper for GDI+) downconverts 16-bit to 8-bit and multiplies single-channel to RGBA, but I haven't tried TIFF yet.